# Prevent automatic driver installation from Windows Update

Tags: windows, driver, freeze

Windowsupdate automatically installs a driver called:

"**Microsoft Remote Desktop Services (Printer) 06/21/2006 6.1.7600.16385**"

This driver causes my system to hang. The only way to restore functionality is to roll back to a restore point.

Of course I've switched off the automatic installation of updates. I've also switched off the (quite hidden) setting for the automatic driver installation (that seems to work independent of the normal Windowsupdate settings!). It is also strange that Windowsupdate re-installs exactly the same version of the driver above **(6.1.7600.16385)**. I saw this when looking at the affected files of the restore point that is created by Windowsupdate. So in fact there would not be any need to install it at all!

As soon as I've restored the system with a restore point, I can boot once without any problems, but then Windowsupdate immediately installs the driver again. The only way to keep my laptop running is to disable the Windowsupdate service. But this is a bad solution! :-(

**Question:** How can the automatic installation of a certain driver be prevented. Or do I need to clean some update caches or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unbelievable simple trick helped to fix the issue:

Simply disable **Remote Desktop**, install the update and then re-enabled it again. Here you can find details on how to enable/disable **Remote Desktop**:

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff710488%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

It's also very interesting to know, that after doing this, I rolled back all changes (restore point) to prove whether this really solved the problem. But I was not able to reproduce it any more. So I can't definitley say whether toggeling the Remote Desktop Support switch did the trick or whether Microsoft has corrected something especially for me :-). But I guess the second option can safely be ignored. ;-)